Given a map, is the determinant preserved regardless of representation?
I was exploring linear algebra a bit, and I stumbled upon a question that is now eating at me. Given a map, is the determinant preserved regardless of representation? Geometrically, I understand that we can think of the determinant as the scaling factor of a map. In a more specific context, the determinant of a map $ℝ^2 -> ℝ^2$ therefore represents the way in which the map scales area. Because this is a quality that is innate to the map itself, my intuition leads me to believe that the determinant should be preserved across representations. So, I created a simple example:
Please forgive me, I am really struggling with using MathJax, so I am going to post photos. Suppose we have the following map, represented with respect to the natural basis vectors:

The determinant of such a matrix is routine: 5.
Suppose, instead, we wanted to represent this same map with respect to basis B:


Again, the determinant is routine: 5.
However, suppose I wanted to "mix" representations. In other words, I want to represent the domain with respect to B and the codomain with respect to the natural basis:

Here, we see that the determinant is 15. This, of course, does not sit well with me, given my initial assumption that the determinant should be preserved, regardless of representation. So, what exactly is going on here? An explanation (especially a conceptual one) would be appreciated.
I fumbled around a bit with the determinant computation and noticed something. We can think of the determinant as the ratio between the area created by the original two bases and the area created by their output vectors: $\frac{Area(f(\beta_1), f(\beta_2))}{Area(\beta_1, \beta_2)}$. In this way, I am curious if mixing different representations affects this ratio. That is, is the numerator computed with respect to the natural basis, whereas the area of the denominator is computed with respect to B?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Linear_maps + $\det(P^{-1}MQ)=(\det P)^{-1}\det M\det Q$, hence $\det(P^{-1}MP)=\det M$.

@AnneBauval Consider the second case I discussed. In that case, we are merely taking the original matrix (its domain and codomain represented by the natural basis) and multiplying by a single matrix so that its domain is represented in terms of B and codomain still represented by the natural basis. Given the equation you provided, unless the matrix we multiply our original matrix by has a determinant of 1, then we will not have the same determinant as before, even though we are representing the same map.

Your last paragraph is exactly correct; when you mix bases like this you are measuring area with respect to two different choice of "units," so to speak, so there's no reason the resulting number should be meaningful. The determinant is a property of a linear map from a vector space to itself, so it can only be meaningfully calculated if you use the same basis for both inputs and outputs.

Your comment, LateGameLank, is correct and a consequence of mine: if $\det Q\ne\det P$ and $\det M\ne0$ then $\det(P^{-1}MQ)\ne\det M$.

You have the right idea. Suppose we have a linear transformation $\mathcal{L}$.
Let $A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}}$ be the matrix of $\mathcal{L}$ in the standard basis $\mathcal{S}$. If you want to represent $\mathcal{L}$ in a different basis, e.g. $\mathcal{B}$, you have to conjugate $A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}}$ with the corresponding orthogonal transformation matrix $U_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}$.
In particular, you get $U_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}} = U_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}^{-1}$ by taking the vectors of $\mathcal{B}$ as the coloumns of $U_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}}$. So we get
$$A_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}} = U_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}}  A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}} U_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}.$$
Now the next thing to remember is, that the determinant is a ring homeomorphism. In particular:
$$\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) \quad \text{and} \quad \det(A^{-1})= \frac{1}{\det(A)}.$$
Thus we have
\begin{align}
\det(A_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}}) &= \det(U_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}}  A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}} U_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}) \\ 
& = \det(U_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}}) \det(  A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}}) \det(U_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}) \\
& = \det(U_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}}) \det(  A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}}) \det(U_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}})^{-1} \\
&= \det(  A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}})
\end{align}
This tells you what you have already noticed; the determinant remains the same if you change basis, but you have to change the basis in the domain and codomain.
If we change the basis only at the begining, we get
$$\det(A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}) = \det(A_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}}) \det(U_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}).$$
Here the determinant changes, it differs precisely by the value of $\det(U_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}})$.
Let me also confirm your geometric intuition of the determinant. In two dimensions, the determinant of the matrix in the standard basis (or any basis as we now know) tells you the are of the paralelogram that is spanned by the two coloumn vectors of the matrix.
